# CardView elevation not working on Android 5.1.1

Tags: android, android-cardview, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I am using CardView inside a RecyclerView.
After reading a lot I ended up with following 'NOT WORKING' code only on Android 5.1.1. On Android Version prior to this one its working nice.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#11ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#11ffffff">
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/primary_bg_light"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/primary_bg_light">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/background_floating_material_light"
                        android:textSize="24sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I did try setting elevation using code also but same result.

Comment: sorry, I don't see where you set elevation in this code..

Comment: where is the attribute `card_view:cardElevation` ?

Comment: also, the parent `RelativeLayout` for `CardView` looks redundant.. I think background #11ffffff is almost black and card shadow might be not visible when you set elevation

Comment: @Blackbelt :  I did try with elevation from xml and also from code , both not working on 5.1.1 when Card View is used in RecyclerView.

Comment: @GennadiiSaprykin : Yeah may be redundant, but I did this as it was a proposed solution for a similar problem on Stack Overflow. Even without background color its not working.

Answer (score 11):

To make it both compatible above or below api 21, you need to specify  app:cardUseCompatPadding="true" in your support CardView.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        app:cardElevation="4dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:cardMaxElevation="6dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just simply add this code to your Card View in xml file!

```
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
```

**You have to import card_view with Alt+Enter !**
And code below will be import in top !.

```
  xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

You'll see elevation is working on android 5 or 5+ .

Answer (score 2):

Remove below line if you used in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

Answer (score 2):

remove this line from `<application ...> </application>` in AndroidManifest.xml file

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

change to

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

for more details [Hardware acceleration](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel?hl=ru)

Answer (score 0):

set in card view

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="6dp"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp">
```