# Card View not proper in 5.1.1 Tablet and 5.0.2 Mobile Device

Tags: android, android-cardview, cornerradius, android-elevation

I am having the following view created with `CardView` .
Adding dependency `compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.+'` in gradle dependency
Below is the xml file for the same.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/cardViewEmp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.50"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
                card_view:cardElevation="10dp"
                android:padding="@dimen/margin_10"
                >
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    >
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/employeeIcon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_5"
                    android:src="@drawable/employeeicon"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Employee"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/employeeIcon"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeNormal"
                    />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/cardViewVehicle"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.50"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
                card_view:cardElevation="10dp"
                android:padding="@dimen/margin_10"
                >
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    >
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/vehicleIconLive"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_5"
                        android:src="@drawable/vehicleicon"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Vehicle"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/vehicleIconLive"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeNormal"
                        />
                </RelativeLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Now the elevation and look and feel for the view in 4.4.4 mobile is as shown below which looks good !
[image]
 
But the same looks very odd in 5.1.1 Nexus Tablet and 5.0.2 Mobile as shown below.
[image]

I have added elevation and corner radius by this

```
card_view:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
card_view:cardElevation="10dp"
```

- Anyone can clearly see the corner radius looks odd without proper elevation.
- What could be the problem.
- What can be done to make the proper look and feel of CardView

**Edit 1:**
Tried with `com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1` , but the output was same again.

Comment: call `compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I have tried the same. Didnt work in 5.1.1 Nexus Tablet!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured out the issue. It was due to the outer `LinearLayout` I had written to make the icons in center of screen which was having height as `wrap_content`. I avoided the `LinearLayout` and through the following code, I made the card view with proper elevation curves and in middle .

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/mainRL"
        >
<android.support.v4.widget.Space
                android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_10"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:id="@+id/spaceCenter"
                />
<!-- Employee icon -->

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/cardViewEmp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
                card_view:cardElevation="10dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/spaceCenter"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                >
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    >
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/employeeIcon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_5"
                    android:src="@drawable/employeeicon"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="  Employee  "
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/employeeIcon"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeNormal"
                    />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <!-- Vehicle icon -->

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/cardViewVehicle"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
                card_view:cardElevation="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spaceCenter"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                >
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    >
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/vehicleIconLive"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_5"
                        android:src="@drawable/vehicleicon"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="    Vehicle     "
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/vehicleIconLive"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeNormal"
                        />
                </RelativeLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try removing: **android:padding** attribute from the card view.

from the docs:

> Since padding is used to offset content for shadows, you cannot set
>   padding on CardView. Instead, you can use content padding attributes
>   in XML or setContentPadding(int, int, int, int) in code to set the
>   padding between the edges of the Card and children of CardView.

Also this:

> Note that, if you specify exact dimensions for the CardView, because
>   of the shadows, its content area will be different between platforms
>   before L and after L. By using api version specific resource values,
>   you can avoid these changes. Alternatively, If you want CardView to
>   add inner padding on platforms L and after as well, you can set
>   setUseCompatPadding(boolean) to true.

Answer (score 0):

To make it both compatible above or below api 21, you need to specify app:cardUseCompatPadding="true" in your support CardView.

credit to ShinChven
[CardView elevation not working on Android 5.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31773274/cardview-elevation-not-working-on-android-5-1-1)