# Android elevation not showing shadow on Button

Tags: java, android, android-studio, button, material-design

### Can't get button shadows to show up.

Stripped down my code to the minimal example:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/my_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:elevation="10dp"
                android:translationZ="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                android:text="BUTTON"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I need that layout structure.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

}
```

Shadows is visible in Android Studio designer:

[image]

But not shown at runtime:

[image]

Tested on:

- Genymotion Google Nexus 5X - Marshmallow 6.0.0 - API 23
- Genymotion Google Nexus 5 - Lollipop 5.1.0 - API 22
- Genymotion Samsung Galaxy S2 - Jelly Bean 4.1.1 - API 16
- Hardware device, Samsung Galaxy S5 mini - KitKat 4.4.2 - API 19

All same result.

I'm using:

- Android Studio 2.1.2
- minSdkVersion 16
- targetSdkVersion 24

Please create a new project in Andriod Studio, Empty Activity template, then copy and paste that code into `activity_main.xml` and `MainActivity.java` so you can test and tell me.

Comment: Directly add your button to ScrollView and see if its showing the shadow or not. It may be due to Linear and RelativeLayout which is wrapping . Check this link for reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35289356/card-view-not-proper-in-5-1-1-tablet-and-5-0-2-mobile-device

Comment: There is no such property `layout_topLeft` for any `View`..!!

Comment: @jankigadhiya yes You Are Right and also in Material design `android:elevation="2dp"` and `android:translationZ="2dp" ` is only work when you set `android:stateListAnimator="@null"` otherwise it is take deafult property.

Comment: Yep, there was a mistake in the sample code, no layout_topLeft. Edited. Still checking out. Thanks!

Answer (score 66, accepted):

> The default `Button` style under `Material` has a `StateListAnimator`
>   that controls the `android:elevation` and `android:translationZ`
>   properties.

<sub>[copied from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27112143/1843331)</sub>

just add this property to your `Button`. you can set your own using the `android:stateListAnimator` property.

```
android:stateListAnimator="@null"
```

**full code :**

```
        <Button
                android:id="@+id/my_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:elevation="2dp"
                android:translationZ="2dp"
                android:stateListAnimator="@null"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                android:text="BUTTON">
```

**UpDate :**

for Understanding I set it 10dp..

**xml code :**

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/my_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:translationZ="10dp"
            android:stateListAnimator="@null"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
            android:text="BUTTON"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: it works! But it works in any emulator with API level 21 or higher. It doesn't work with API 20 or lower.  I will open up another question about an alternative for lower apis. Thanks!

Comment: pixel perfect alert: note that `wrap_content` height set for `Button`s parent is cutting out top and bottom shadow, as on screenshot. always remeber to adjust proper margins

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `android:outlineProvider="bounds"` if elevation doesn't work with your view !

(I've simplified the code below for the exemple)

**View:**

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/view"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:outlineProvider="bounds"
    android:elevation="20dp" >
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

It was working in my case, Give it a try `app:elevation`

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/my_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_topLeft="20dp"
    app:elevation="2dp"
    android:translationZ="2dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    android:text="BUTTON">
```

Comment: "Unexpected namespace prefix.."

Comment: app: prefix is not available in button

Comment: Oh my god.. You have to add namespace first. Dont downvote if you dont know. Tell me to add more specification. I will explain it.

Comment: Even if you add app namespace, default `stateListAnimator` overrides `elevation` in both namespaces. I wrote the previous comment in a hurry