# Some questions about buttons..(elevation, click effect, etc.)

Tags: android, properties, android-button

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/delete_set"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_remove_routine"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:translationZ="3dp"
    android:stateListAnimator="@null"
    android:text="Remove Set"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:textColor="@color/orgin_text_color"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/add_set"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_add_routine"
    android:text="ADD SET"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:translationZ="3dp"
    android:stateListAnimator="@null"
    android:textColor="@color/orgin_text_color"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"/>
```

[image]

The xml code and pictures are the UI I made.

I want to go ahead with this design.

I have referenced this link.
[Android elevation not showing shadow on Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38278179/android-elevation-not-showing-shadow-on-button/38278308)

**Q1. How can you give the button click effect in this situation?**

I want to give the `button` an `elevation` effect.

Normally it didn't apply when using the elevation property.

So I used the `android:stateListAnimator="@null"` attribute.
Works fine.

However, when I click, the button click effect does not appear.

The reason was the `stateListAnimator` property. When I delete this, the button click effect appears.

However, if i delete this, `the depth of the elevation` property cannot be adjusted.

So maybe I need this property for elavation.

---

**Q2. When choosing a button color, what's the difference between `background` and `backgroundTint`?**

When I first set the color of the button, I used the `background="@color/white"` property.

But the color has not changed.

In that link, obviously we use the `background` property for the button's color.

The case I use the background property of a button is when I use `background="?android:selectableItemBackground"` and `background="#00ff0000"`.

These two properties make it completely transparent except for the text on the button.

---

**Q3. Why doesn't `background="@color/white`" apply?**

In connection with Q2, I am curious about why the color does not change when a color is specified with the `background` property.

Comment: please don't ask multiple questions at once, it doesn't help people in future. stick to asking one question at a time or your question will be closed, then you find no answers either way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all, it's not the best way to ask multiple questions at once! and for your questions, here's a hint :

- Use a [MaterialButton](https://ahsensaeed.com/android-material-design-library-material-button/) instead of a normal button:

  `<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>`
- Visit [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38080463/13289575) for your second question